# Trouble with resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf

I recently tried to delete unoDNS from my laptop. A member of their team gave me some commands to input in a terminal. It looked like it changed the nameserver address back to 8.8.8.8. But after I restarted my laptop I cant connect to internet at all. I am using ubuntu 14.04. Please help.